# Pass a pandas dataframe to Django template

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

I am creating a website using Django, bootstrap3 and Dajaxice.  I want to pass a pandas dataframe from my views.py to one of my templates but am having trouble getting it to work.  I need it as a dataframe and not html so using `.to_html()` isn't an option.

**The html**:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="UpdateDB" onclick="submitverify({{file_dfs}})">Submit Files {% bootstrap_icon "chevron-right" %}</button> 
</div>
```

When I try to pass `file_dfs` I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error on `{{file_dfs}}`.  When I open chromes developer tool it looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="UpdateDB" onclick="submitverify({&#39;_COMM_&#39;: [], &#39;_CMD_&#39;: [         WINDOW_START ...]})"
```

Can anyone help me out on this??

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more information about what you're trying to do?  Are you trying to pass the data frame to some other user of the data?

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie yes I need the dataframe in another function called through my html template.

Comment: Is the function a python function or a django function?  I'm not sure the django parser would know how to deal with a dataframe.  You might look at https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie the function is a javascript function containing a dajax call.  The dajax is what uses the dataframe but the javascript call happens in my html template, which is why I need to be able to pass the dataframe from my views.py into my template.  I know it's not dajax causing the problem because I get the same error even when dajax is commented out.  It seems like the template just gets confused when it sees the datafame.

Comment: Is auto escaping turned on?  It appears that Django has it turned on by default.  (see https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping).  If it is turned on, you need to turn it off for the data frame, I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Is auto escaping turned on? It appears that Django has it turned on by default (see [code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AutoEscaping)). If it is turned on, you need to turn it off for the data frame.